# Recovering the contents of the clipboard in OSX

Tags: macos, clipboard

Is there any way to retrieve the contents of the clipboard in OSX? By mistake, I overwrote the contents, and I lost some important content.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately not.

Tools like the famous [QuickSilver](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/14831/quicksilver) and [Jumpcut](http://jumpcut.sourceforge.net/) can save you from this mistake in the future.

Comment: Or, do what I do, put stuff you want to save in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's gone.

There are a couple of great [clipboard managers](http://theappleblog.com/2009/06/02/10-clipboard-managers-for-os-x/) that will help prevent this in the future though.